# Fresh installation by npx react-native init myapp causes in problem warning

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, import

I do the terminalcommand `npx react-native init myapp`. Change the dir to /myapp and vs code shows me this problem warning:

[image: Error small]
[image: Error]

There are some more Errors like this in the file, without doing anything.

[image: Another Error]

What did I miss?

Comment: What happens if `.js` file extension is changed to `.ts` file extension?

Comment: red line disappear, return 'crashed' because of `style={styles.sectionContainer}`

Comment: But it also crashed before changing the extension right?

Comment: No. Only the redlines as 'problem' in my images above.

Comment: Can you make a global search for `App.js` in your project? It might be imported somewhere or mentioned in some configuration file. It must change to `.ts` as well.

Comment: Yeah I could but this doen't solve the weird feeling of create a new applikation and immediately ran into this redlines. As a beginner this is really confusing.

Comment: This is an error that is created by VSCode only. Your app runs without doing anything. If we change the file extension to `.ts` which is the default for typescript files, then VSCode does not throw an error. Of course, if this file has been previously imported somewhere else, it might cause a crash since we have changed it. We can get rid of this message without changing the code by adding `"javascript.validate.enable": false` to the VSCode settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this is a VSCode error only, since the application is using `TypeScript` annotations and the default file extension for typescript files is `.ts`. It could be solved by changing the file extension to `.ts` and possibly change occurrences of `App.js` in the project to `App.ts`.

However, this error message does not effect the runtime behavior. Since it might be desired to *not* change any code, we can get rid of the error message by changing the VSCode settings.

This is done by setting `"javascript.validate.enable": false`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not an Error. It shows the return type of the Function you ca change it to.

```
const App = () => {
return(
    <View>
    </View>
)

}
```

Comment: yeah, maybe. But why does a fresh and clean installation needed this improvement?

Comment: you can run it. it is not an error. only the syntax is different

Comment: Ok. Feels weird for me as a beginner. Wont imagine how confused other people are.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>hello world!</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```